# List directories using the PHP Azure Blob Storage SDK

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

Here is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
 $key = 'keywithsomeID';
 $blobListOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
 $blobListOptions->setPrefix($key);

 $blob_list = $blobClient->listBlobs($container, $blobListOptions);
 $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();
```

Now, what I get returned is the following:

FolderA/Subfolder/FileA
FolderA/File1
FolderA/File2
FolderA/File3

And really I'd just like to specify some option where I only get the result "FolderA".

Any thoughts? I feel like I'm missing something but also the PHP SDK is not particularly well-documented or helpful.

Edit: The github being used: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php

Comment: Please try to add following line of code `$blobListOptions->setDelimiter("/");` after `$blobListOptions->setPrefix($key);`.

Comment: This gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As @Gaurav pointed out, you'll need to specify the value `/` as delimiter option first.

2) You'll also need to replace the following line of code

```
$blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();
```

with

```
$blobs = $blob_list->getBlobPrefixes();
```